# finding quantile of the generalized normal distribution

Tags: matlab, quantile

I am writing a Matlab code for finding quantile of the generalized normal distribution

```
x ~ GN(0, alfa, beta) :
p(x; 0, alfa, beta) = (beta/(2*alfa*gamma(1/beta))) * exp(-(abs(x)/alfa).^beta )
```

According to quantile formula shown in [Generalized normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution),
for quantile C, I calculated quantile by

```
z_c = sign(C-0.5).*gaminv(2*abs(C-0.5), 1./beta, 1./(alfa.^beta)).^(1./beta)+0
```

To validate the equation above, I assigned alfa=sqrt(2) and beta=2 to make the generalized normal to be a normal distribution. But when I calculated

```
>> C=0.05; beta =2; alfa =sqrt(2);
>> z_c = sign(C-0.5).*gaminv(2*abs(C-0.5), 1./beta, 1./(alfa.^beta)).^(1./beta)
z_c =
   -0.8224
```

I thought the result should be exactly the same as the quantile of the inverse of the normal CDF with mean mu=0 and standard deviation sigma=1, however,

```
>> norminv(C)
ans =
   -1.6449
```

Could anyone help to point out the mistake(s) made above?

Comment: Where this`alfa = sqrt(2)` come from ? You've solve `alfa^2/2 = 1` ?

Comment: @obchardon Yes, I assign alfa=sqrt(2) and beta=2 such that p(x; 0, alfa, beta) = (beta/(2*alfa*gamma(1/beta))) * exp(-(abs(x)/alfa).^beta ) becomes N(0,1)

Comment: you may want to have a look at [`quantile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/quantile.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right answer:

```
z_c2 = sign(C-0.5).*((1).*gaminv(2*abs(C-0.5), 1./beta, alfa^beta)).^(1./beta)+0
```